# Imagemagick combine multiple tifs in an orderly manner

Tags: linux, imagemagick, tiff

Please help me! i have been trying for over three days to combine tif images which i scanned together into one single tif so i can ocr it with microsoft document imaging... i have been looking for a simple solution, then i found imagemagic by doing an extensive google search. but when i do :

```
convert +compress *.tif combination.tif
```

i do get the combined tif file...but for some strange reason, imagemagic will not add the pages alphanumerically even if the images are named progressively... please what do i do?

example: i have `scannedimage-1`,`scannedimage-2`, `scannedimage-11`

imagemagick might combine them thus:
 `scannedimage-1,scannedimage-11,scannedimage-2`

please help as i am getting frustrated.

Comment: It looks like the pages were added alphanumerically. The string compare looks at characters, not numbers. You need to name them 01, 02, 03, ... if you want a string compare to put them in correct numerical order.

Comment: @Burbank I did name them with zero fill e.g scannedimage-01 and so on but no luck any other suggestions please

Comment: I'm not an expert in imagemagick, but if naming them sequentially didn't work, then it appears that it's loading the files in the order the operating system provides them. The only thing I can think of is to write a script which gathers the list of names, sorts them, then passes them to imagemagick. Unfortunately I can't help you with this.

Comment: I think imagemagick has some kind of inbuilt algorithm for sorting the files cos even when I do `convert image1, image2,image3 -append combination.tif` imagemagick still rearranged the image and there are some blank pages that appear in the combined image.... sigh...

Comment: If you were working on Windows, I could offer to create a command line utility with my imaging library, but I don't have anything set up at the moment to build for Linux.

Comment: thanks for your concern and effort... i believe there should be an option with the imagemagic command to ensure the images are ordered accordingly... besides i could do windows cos i got windows on virtualbox vm....so can u help? need to combine several tiff images...can your library do that?

Comment: I have worked on tiff merge functions, but my latest code needs testing. I could probably get it to work in a short time, but it would not be free. If you want to continue this conversation, email me (bitbank@pobox.com).